# ngAnimateSwap limitations

Tags: angularjs, opacity, ng-animate

I have used ngAnimateSwap to translate elements horizontally, vertically. However are other types of animations supported, such as opacity (fade-in and fade-out?)

When I modify the example that appears here [animateSwap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateSwap) to use `opacity` instead of the `top` value, then the animation does not occur. Is this expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working using `opacity`. You have to play around with the css and understand what css element does what. [Here's a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yjdSudPTJIutjmxML9RC?p=preview) of `animateSwap` being used with an `opacity` transition.

The original css is:

```
.swap-animation.ng-enter {
  top:-250px;
}
.swap-animation.ng-enter-active {
  top:0px;
}
.swap-animation.ng-leave {
  top:0px;
}
.swap-animation.ng-leave-active {
  top:250px;
}
```

I changed that to the following and I now have a crossfade working just fine:

```
.swap-animation.ng-enter {
  top:0px;
  opacity:0;
}
.swap-animation.ng-enter-active {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
}
.swap-animation.ng-leave {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
}
.swap-animation.ng-leave-active {
  top:0px;
  opacity:0;
}
```